# Can't add custom configuration options for module in backend - 404 page not found

Tags: magento-1.8, module, admin, configuration, backend

I was following different tutorials from the internet and from books, but none of them works.

Let's follow this tutorial (https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-back-end-configuration-in-magento--cms-23265)

**app/etc/modules/Envato_All.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Envato_CustomConfig>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Envato_CustomConfig>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Envato/CustomConfig/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Envato_CustomConfig>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Envato_CustomConfig>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <customconfig>
                <class>Envato_CustomConfig_Helper</class>
            </customconfig>
        </helpers>
        <models>
             <customconfig>
                <class>Envato_CustomConfig_Model</class>
             </customconfig>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <customconfig_options>
                                            <title>Custom Configuration Section</title>
                                        </customconfig_options>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Envato/CustomConfig/etc/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <customconfig translate="label" module="customconfig">
            <label>Custom Configuration Tab</label>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        </customconfig>
    </tabs>

    <sections>
        <customconfig_options translate="label" module="customconfig">
            <label>Custom Configuration Settings</label>
            <tab>customconfig</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <section_one translate="label">
                    <label>Section One</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                
                    <fields>
                        <custom_field_one>
                            <label>Custom Text Field</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Example of text field.</comment>                   
                        </custom_field_one>
                    </fields>
                </section_one>
                <section_two translate="label">
                    <label>Section Two</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                
                    <fields>
                        <custom_field_two>
                            <label>Custom Select Field</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>customconfig/options</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Example of select field.</comment>
                        </custom_field_two>
                        <custom_field_three>
                            <label>Custom Radio Field</label>
                            <frontend_type>radios</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>customconfig/options</source_model>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Example of radios field.</comment>
                        </custom_field_three>
                        <custom_field_four>
                            <label>Custom Multiselect Field</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>customconfig/options</source_model>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Example of multiselect field.</comment>
                        </custom_field_four>
                    </fields>
                </section_two>
            </groups>                
        </customconfig_options>
    </sections>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Envato/CustomConfig/Model/Options.php**

```
<?php
class Envato_CustomConfig_Model_Options
{
  /**
   * Provide available options as a value/label array
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function toOptionArray()
  {
    return array(
      array('value'=>1, 'label'=>'One'),
      array('value'=>2, 'label'=>'Two'),
      array('value'=>3, 'label'=>'Three'),            
      array('value'=>4, 'label'=>'Four')                     
    );
  }
}
```

**app/code/local/Envato/CustomConfig/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Sample Widget Helper
 */
class Envato_CustomConfig_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

As Result I get this:

[image]

But if I click on "Custom Configuration Settings" in the left, then I get this:

[image]

How can I successfully add configuration options for my extension?

Answer (score 0):

It works after login out from the backend and login in again.
The tutorial creator said, that Magento uses a cache for backend too.

---

If you still fail to add custom configuration to your module and get the 404 page, then you are probably missing the ACL protection.

You have to add this code to your `config.xml`:

```
<config>    
    <!-- ... -->
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <enter_your_section_name_here>
                                            <title>Hello</title>
                                        </enter_your_section_name_here>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
    <!-- ... -->
</config>
```

Don't forget to clear the magento cache and logout and login from the backend to apply the settings.

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6426041/4684797).